# Codeigniter Delete ... Where ... and

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-delete

I need a little help.
How can i send this query with codeigniter?

```
Delete FROM friendconnect WHERE who = 5 and whos = 1 OR whos = 5 and who = 1;
```

I found only that:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->delete('mytable');
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: it just works but not nice: $this->db->where("(whos = '$senderid' and who = '$friendid' OR who = '$senderid' and whos = '$friendid')");

Comment: the documentation should tell you this.: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('who', 5);
$this->db->where('whos', 1);
$this->db->or_where('whos', 5);
$this->db->where('who', 1);

$this->db->delete('friendconnect');
```

This is also an alternative:

```
$this->db->where('who', 5)->where('whos', 1)->or_where('whos', 5)->where('who', 1);
$this->db->delete('friendconnect');
```

This also:

```
$this->db->where(array('who'=>5, array('whos'=>1)))->or_where('whos', 5)->where('who', 1);
$this->db->delete('friendconnect');
```

More info: [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just use this `$this->db->query("Delete FROM friendconnect WHERE who = 5 and whos = 1 OR whos = 5 and who = 1");`

Comment: Maybe this query its not enough safety?

Comment: For safety you can use stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->where('(who = 5 and whos = 1) OR (whos = 5 and who = 1)');
$this->db->delete('friendconnect');
```